# How many Green Lanterns has Earth had?

Tags: dc, green-lantern

I know the "Big 5", Jennifer-Lynn Hayden, Simon Baz, and I'd probably throw G'Nort and Kilowog in there as well, but surely there are more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Green Lantern Corps Quarterly 02 (Autumn 92) - "The Lonely Man" - Waverly Sayre, American frontiersman, 19th Century

Charlie Vicker

Green Lantern Corps Quarterly 04 (Spring 93) - "The Best Choice" - Donna Parker, c.1956

Alan Scott

Hal Jordan

John Stewart

Guy Gardner

Kyle Rayner

Jennifer-Lynn Hayden-Scott (Jade)

Simon Baz

Jessica Cruz (Power Ring)

Niti ________ (human female) Superboy v5 #33 (Sep 2014) - alternate timeline

Most can be found on the [Green Lantern Wiki](http://greenlantern.wikia.com/wiki/Green_Lantern_Wiki).

Comment: There's also the chinese one from Green Lantern v3 #19. Yalan Gur, whose battery became Alan Scott's lantern in a wierd retcon. http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Yalan_Gur_(New_Earth)

Comment: Good catch.  I have that one but forgot it.

Answer (score 2):

Just post-Crisis, there was [The Green Lantern Corps of Earth](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Green_Lantern_Corps_of_Earth): In addition to Hal, John, Kilowog and sometimes Guy, there were also Katma Tui, Salaak, Ch'p, and Arisa, sometimes joined by Driq.

In the possible-future [The Last Days of Animal Man](http://www.comicvine.com/green-lantern-circa-2029/4005-64457/), there was a whale or whale-like Green Lantern on Earth whose backstory is not explored.